# Flutter how to make showDateRangePicker view only month?

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-datetime-picker, flutter-date-range-picker

Now my showDateRangePicker looks like this:

[image]

I'm using the syncfusion_flutter_datepicker package looked at the documentation, couldn't find anything that could help me out

How can I make my calendar view only display by month and not by day?

Code:

```
  Future<void> _selectDate(BuildContext context) async {
    final DateTimeRange? picked = await showDateRangePicker(
      locale: const Locale('ru', 'RU'),
      saveText: 'Сохранить',
      cancelText: 'Отмена',
      helpText: 'Выберите дату',
      fieldEndLabelText: 'Конец',
      fieldStartLabelText: 'Начало',
      context: context,
      builder: (BuildContext context, Widget? child) {
        return Theme(
          data: ThemeData.light().copyWith(
            colorScheme: const ColorScheme.light(
              primary: Colors.blue,
              onPrimary: Colors.white,
              onSurface: Colors.black,
            ),
            dialogBackgroundColor: Colors.white,
          ),
          child: child!,
        );
      },
      firstDate: DateTime(2021),
      lastDate: DateTime.now(),
      initialDateRange: selectedDateRange ??
          DateTimeRange(
            start: DateTime(DateTime.now().year, DateTime.now().month, 1),
            end: DateTime.now(),
          ),
    );
    if (picked != null) {
      selectedDateRange = picked;
      final pickedDate =
          '${picked.start.toString().substring(0, 10)} - ${picked.end.toString().substring(0, 10)}';
      final AmanDate =
          '${picked.start.toString().substring(0, 10)}/${picked.end.toString().substring(0, 10)}';
      _dateController.text = pickedDate;
      _attendanceBloc.add(LoadAttendance(date: AmanDate));
    }
  }
```